# Is the word "colic" a right word in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I drink too much water and run or do some extreme activities, I will feel something in my stomach. I also want to stop doing the activities because of that feeling as well. It's not hurting, aching, or feeling nauseous.

I use a dictionary to translate this word from my native language to English and it says "colic." But when I look up this word, it is not the same.

What word should I use to describe this feeling?

Comment: It's not clear what you're feeling from the description. The only non-pain, non-nauseous feeling I can think of that occurs in the stomach is growls of hunger. Also, sadness can cause feelings in the stomach, but it doesn't sound like that's what you mean.

Comment: What's the word in your language? When you looked up its English equivalent, was there more than one answer? If your stomach is NOT aching, nauseated or hurting, why do feel the need to stop exercising? Some discomfort or pain must be involved. OR did you mean that the word you're looking for is NOT ANY of those listed?

Comment: In my native language, the word that I am looking for is a little less than pain. I think there might be no English equivalent word.

Comment: Uneasiness, discomfort, bloating, pressure,... Who knows what you are feeling? How to know what it is, from such a vague description? You really need to investigate more, threading your way through thesauri and dictionaries, from word to word, if you cannot describe the symptoms better here.

Comment: As Mari-Lou asked: what is your native language, and what is the word in your native language? Maybe someone here knows that language and will understand what you’re talking about, because your explanation of what this feeling is is so vague that it’s impossible to guess at what you actually mean.

Comment: I am taking "It's not hurting, aching, or nauseous" to mean that none of these words apply to your situation. If that is the case, then you should edit your answer and write something like: **The words *hurt*, *ache* and *nauseous* do not fit.**

Comment: My native language is Thai and "จุก" is the word we use to express this feeling.

Answer (score 3):

[Cramp](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cramp) is the word you're looking for.

> noun
>
> Often, cramps.
>
> - a sudden, involuntary, spasmodic contraction of a muscle or group of
>     muscles, especially of the extremities, sometimes with severe pain.
> - a piercing pain in the abdomen.
> - an intermittent,
>     painful contraction of structures of a wall containing involuntary
>     muscle, as in biliary colic or in the uterine contractions of
>     menstruation or of labor.

Answer (score 3):

Reading from the comments, and thinking why a person would suddenly stop doing exercise, the word *stitch* popped into mind.

A *stitch* is often a short sharp pain,  localized, usually felt in the side of your stomach. It's similar to *cramp*, but a *stitch* passes more quickly and is much less painful. As OD defines it,

> [**Stitch**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stitch) 2) A sudden sharp pain in the side of the body, caused by strenuous     exercise:
>   *he was panting and had a stitch*

Comment: Sometimes, you get a *stitch in your side* when you've been exercising vigorously. You'll know the sensation if you've had it. This is a good idiomatic expression.

Comment: Someone edited this post with the following summary: *Include text attribution, which was hidden in violation of the mod directive on meta about this* And yet, on the same page, there are two other answers with links and no attributions. If you're going to start a witch hunt, ("violation" I ask you) do it properly I say.

Comment: I get it now. Some user is looking for easy rep, every edit is +2 and s/he is sifting through each and every post so they can "include text attribution".

Answer (score 0):

Try [upset](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aupset&oq=define%3Aupset&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2782j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=define:upset) stomach or [indigestion](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aupset&oq=define%3Aupset&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2782j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=define:indigestion).

Answer (score -1):

Dyspeptic: of or having indigestion or **consequent irritability or depression**.

Comment: Drinking water and then doing exercise is not dyspepsia.

Comment: Please provide a reference for your definition.